# How to remove a pattern from File Names in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

I have multiple files as below

```
File1[Pattern].txt
File2[Pattern].txt
File3[Pattern].txt
```

I want to remove [Pattern] from all the files in a directory.

And finally, the file names should be as below.

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
```

Comment: Can you give an example of [Pattern]?

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` parameter expansion (`${f%%\[*\]*}`) to strip off the portion starting from (first) `[` (from left), and using `mv` to rename:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f%%\[*\]*}".txt; done
```

Drop `echo` for actual action.

---

With `rename` (`prename`), the matched group `1` matches the portion before first `[` and second group matches literal `.txt`. In the replacement we have just used the captured groups:

```
rename -n 's/^([^[]+)\[[^]]+\](\.txt)$/$1$2/' *.txt
```

Drop -`n` for actual action.